# Is $P(X,Y)=a + aY + (b+cX^2)Y^n \in \mathbb Z [X][Y]$ irreducible?

Tags: polynomials

I am considering the polynomial $a + aY + (b+cX^2)Y^n\in \mathbb Z [X][Y]$, with $n$ even and $a,b,c$ non zero integers. Is this polynomial irreducible or not?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by irreducible? If $a= b = c$ not a unit,  then $a$ is a non-trivial divisor, so it is not irreducible. But this might not be what you  want to know.

Answer (score 1):

If $a=0$, then the polynomial is $\left(b+cX^2\right)Y^n$ which is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if
(1) $\gcd(b,c) \neq 1$, 
(2) $n >1$, 
(3) $n=1$ and either $|b|>1$ or $c\neq 0$, or 
(4) $n=0$, $c=\sigma \mu^2$, and $b$ is equal to $-\sigma \nu^2$, where $\mu,\nu\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\sigma\in\{-1,+1\}$ are such that $\mu \neq 0$ or $|\nu|>1$.
From now on we assume that $a\neq 0$.

If $c=0$, then the polynomial is $a+aY+bY^n$.  If $\gcd(a,b)\neq 1$, then this polynomial is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.  If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then consider two cases:
(i) If $b=0$, then $a=\pm1$ and the polynomial is $\pm(1+Y)$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$;
(ii) If $b\neq 0$, then the irreducibility of $a+aY+bY^n$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ is the same as the irreducibility of $Y^n+\frac{a}{b}Y+\frac{a}{b}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, but I am not sure if there is a full characterization of which values of $\frac{a}{b}$ and $n$ would make this polynomial irreducible.

Now, assume that $c\neq 0$.  In the case where $\gcd(a,b,c)\neq 1$, it is obvious that the given polynomial is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.  Suppose from now on that $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$.  If $n=0$, then the given polynomial is $(a+b)+aY+cX^2$.  Since the ideal $\big((a+b)+aY\big)$ of the integral domain $\mathbb{Q}[Y]$ is prime, we can argue by Eisenstein's Criterion that $(a+b)+aY+cX^2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, whence also over $\mathbb{Z}$.

From now on, assume that $n\geq 1$.  Taking modulo $Y$, we conclude that, if $a+aY+\left(b+cX^2\right)Y^n$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, then either
(a) $a+aY+\left(b+cX^2\right)Y^n=\left(f(Y)+XY\,g(Y)+X^2Y\,h(Y)\right)\,t(Y)$ for some polynomials $f(Y),g(Y),h(Y),t(Y)\in\mathbb{Z}[Y]$ with $t(Y) \neq \pm 1$, or
(b) $a+aY+\left(b+cX^2\right)Y^n=\left(f_1(Y)+XY\,g_1(Y)\right)\left(f_2(Y)+XY\,g_2(Y)\right)$ for some polynomials $f_1(Y),f_2(Y),g_1(Y),g_2(Y)\in\mathbb{Z}[Y]$ (note that this case may hold only when $n\geq 2$).

**Case (a):** We have $h(Y)\,t(Y)=cY^n$ and $f(Y)\,t(Y)=a+aY$.  Therefore, $t(Y)$ must be constant.  However, since $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$, we must have $t(Y)=\pm 1$, which is a contradiction.  (This part concludes that, if $n=1$, then $a+aY+\left(b+cX^2\right)Y^n$ is irreducible.)

**Case (b):** We have $f_1(Y)\,f_2(Y)=a+aY+bY^n$, $f_1(Y)\,g_2(Y)+f_2(Y)\,g_1(Y)=0$, and $g_1(Y)\,g_2(Y)=cY^{n-2}$.  Hence, $g_1(Y)=c_1Y^{n_1}$ and $g_2(Y)=c_2Y^{n_2}$ for some $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n_1,n_2\in\mathbb{N}_0$ such that $n_1+n_2=n-2$ and $c_1c_2=c$.  If $n_1\neq n_2$, then the condition $f_1(Y)\,g_2(Y)+f_2(Y)\,g_1(Y)=0$ implies that $Y$ divides $f_1(Y)$ or $f_2(Y)$, contradicting the equality $f_1(Y)\,f_2(Y)=a+aY+bY^n$.  Thus, $n_1=n_2$, whence $n$ is even, so $n_1=\frac{n}{2}-1$ and $n_2=\frac{n}{2}-1$.  Ergo,
$$F(Y):=c_2\,f_1(Y)=-c_1\,f_2(Y)\,.$$
That is, 
$$-\big(F(Y)\big)^2=\left(c_2\,f_1(Y)\right)\left(c_1\,f_2(Y)\right)=c\left(a+aY+bY^n\right)\,.$$
Hence, $a+aY+bY^n$ has a multiple root $\omega$ in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.  The derivative of $a+aY+bY^n$ is $a+nbY^{n-1}$.  We then have $a+nb\omega^{n-1}=0$.  This means $$0=a+a\omega+b\omega^n=a+a\omega-\frac{a}{n}\omega\,,\text{ or }
\omega=-\frac{n}{n-1}\,.$$
Hence, the only possible root $Y=\omega$ of $a+aY+bY^n$ is $\omega=-\frac{n}{n-1}$.  That is, for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$k\big((n-1)Y+n\big)^n=a+aY+bY^n\,.$$
This is possible if and only if $n=2$, where $(a,b)=\lambda(4,1)$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $\gcd(\lambda,c)=1$.  If this is the case, the given polynomial is thus
$$cX^2Y^2+\lambda(Y+2)^2=\left(c_1XY+\lambda_1 (Y+2)\right)\left(c_2XY+\lambda_2(Y+2)\right)\,,$$
for some $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\lambda_1\lambda_2=\lambda$.  Ergo, $c_1\lambda_2+c_2\lambda_1=0$.  Since $\gcd(\lambda,c)=1$, we conclude that $c=su^2$ and $\lambda=-sv^2$ for some $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\gcd(u,v)=1$ and $s\in\{-1,+1\}$.  That is, $(a,b,c)=\left(-4sv^2,-sv^2,su^2\right)$.

---

**Synopsis:**

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$.  Consider the polynomial $a+aY+\left(b+cX^2\right)Y^n$.  It is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if either 
(A) $\gcd(a,b,c)\neq 1$, or
(B) $n=2$ and $(a,b,c)=\pm\left(4v^2,v^2,-u^2\right)$ for some $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}$.
The same polynomial is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $n=2$ and $(a,b,c)=\pm\left(4v^2,v^2,-u^2\right)$ for some $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}$.  It is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$ iff $n=2$, $a=4b$, and $ac<0$.  Finally, this polynomial is reducible over some algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if $n=2$ and $a=4b$.

Now, suppose that $a,b,c$ may be zero.  Then, $a+aY+\left(b+cX^2\right)Y^n$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if
(I) $\gcd(a,b,c)\neq 1$,
(II) $a=0$ and $n>1$,
(III) $a=0$, $n=1$, and $|b|>1$, 
(IV) $a=0$, $n=1$, and $c\neq 0$, 
(V) $n=0$, $c=\sigma \mu^2$, and $b$ is equal to $-\sigma \nu^2$, where $\mu,\nu\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\sigma\in\{-1,+1\}$ are such that $\mu \neq 0$ or $|\nu|>1$,
(VI) $c=0$, $b\neq 0$, and $Y^n+\frac{a}{b}Y+\frac{a}{b}$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, or
(VII) $n=2$ and $(a,b,c)=\pm\left(4v^2,v^2,-u^2\right)$ for some $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Reducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ holds iff (II), (IV), (V), (VI), or (VII) is satisfied.  Reducibility over $\mathbb{R}$ holds iff (II), (IV), or one of the following conditions is satisfied:
(V') $a=0$, $n=0$, $c\neq 0$, and $bc \leq 0$,
(VI') $c=0$, $b\neq 0$, and either $n=2$ with $\frac{a}{b} \in (-\infty,0]\cup[4,+\infty)$ or $n>2$, and
(VII') $n=2$, $a=4b$, and $ac<0$.
Reducibility over some algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$ happens iff (II), (IV), or any of the following conditions is met:
(V'') $a=0$, $n=0$, and $c\neq 0$,
(VI'') $c=0$, $b\neq 0$, and $n>1$, and
(VII'') $n=2$ and $a=4b$.